# Import class problem in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, import, package

I have 2 packages each in a different project , one package is called ch6 which includes class X , the other package is game which includes class Gamer , when trying to import game.Gamer manually in X I get error : "The import game cannot be resolved " , but when I hover on the red line of the error and choose "fix project setup.." , a dialog box appears offering importing the project of class game to the path of project of X and things are fixed, why can't I add the game.Gamer manually although I use the same syntax ?

*** EDIT ***

Including code as requested:

**project ch6:**

```
package ch6; 

abstract public class X {
    private int x = 7;
    public static final int y = 24;
}
```

**project HFJ:**

```
package game;

public class Gamer {
    public int z;
}
```

Comment: Please include declaration of class X and Gamer, with package structure intact. Also, if this is homework please tag it as so.

Comment: (I think it might be homework related, and if it is a test to pass Eclipse setups you should be studying algorithms and data-structures instead). But... you should look into the build path, your project probably isn't on the build path, on a path conflict the "top one" will win in the build. As such, the import you want should be on top. Also--that's a nasty namespace collision and you should do your best to avoid it.

Comment: project ch6:

package ch6;

abstract public class X {

private int x = 7;

public static final int y = 24;
}

project HFJ:

package game;

public class Gamer {

public int z;

}

and No it isn't a homework , it is my trial to implement examples in Head first Java book

Answer (score 1):

If you have two Eclipse projects it should look something like:

```
[Project ch6]
  -java
  -Build Path
   ....
[Project game]
  -java
  -Build Path
  ...
```

To import cross project you want -> (you can get to the path a number of ways)

```
  [right click] ch6 -> Properties -> Build Path  
  Projects Tab -> Check [game] || (add) Project [game];
```

Then do a clean build. That should resolve the import and combine the paths.

edit: reversed the order per Ed's suggestion.

Comment: aha , then  waiting for eclipse to fix and resolve imports between different projects won't work when declaring a class of a project in another project ?

Comment: @aur Eclipse will often find the correct package (especially after a clean build so it can scan the classpath) but it isn't perfect--especially when you have a lot of projects. I would spend time doing it manually so you can troubleshoot. Its a great IDE but it has its quirks...

Comment: @Ed & Daniel : thank you very much for answering , hope I didn't bother you

Answer (score 0):

I think you might see this if you didn't use the correct directory structure - if game.Gamer.java wasn't stored as /game/Gamer.java.

Also, if you haven't already, try refreshing the project (select the project in the tree, then menu File..Refresh.

Comment: I checked the structure of the directory but i found it correct , also i tried to refresh both projects but nothing happened

Comment: Ah... did you make the gamer project a dependency of the ch6 project?  If not, that's your problem.  Er... see Daniel's new answer - same thing.